# Algolia rails Invalid index/slave name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I have two master indexes(Content,SubContent) with four slave indexes each.
When i tried

```
Content.raw_search "", slave: ""
```

works fine.

```
SubContent.raw_search "", slave: "Latest"
```

also works fine.

```
SubContent.raw_search "", slave: ""
# > ArgumentError: Invalid index/slave name:
```

Is there any mistakes on my side?

Comment: You should open a GH issue: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails

Comment: I have observed, running rails console, that the first time I hit a particular slave index I receive this error, then pressing "up arrow" and retrying the exact same command returns good results.